# how to multiply a matrix with every cell of cell array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, product

I have a 4D array `A` size(l,k,s,r) and a cell array `B` size(i,j) where in each cell a different 4D array of coefficients size(l,k,s,r) is stored.

I want to make changes in the given array `C` of size(i,j) = `C(i,j) + sum(sum(sum(sum(A.*B{i,j}))))` without `for` loop.

in other words I need to extract one by one all arrays out of cell array `B` and multiply with `A`.

with the for loop i do it this way:

```
for i=1:length_of_first_dimension
    for j=1:length_of_second_dimension
        B_4D=B{i,j};       % extraction of 4D array
        dummy(i,j)=sum(sum(sum(sum(B_4D.*A))));
    end
end
C=C+dummy;
```

can anyone help me with that?

Comment: could you please give more detailed information about the way i can do that? what exactly should i reshape?

Comment: It is [best not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) `B` into a `(length_of_first_dimension*length_of_second_dimension)`-by-`l*k*s*r` 2D matrix

```
rB = cellfun( @(x) x(:).', B, 'uni', 0 ); %'
rB = vertcat(rB{:});
```

Now, `reshape` `A` into a `l*k*s*r`-by-1 column vector

```
rA = A(:);
```

And simply multiply them

```
rDummy = rB * rA; %// does the elem-wise product and summation quite quickly.
```

Reshape the result

```
dummy = reshape(rDummy, size(B) );
C = C + dummy;
```

---

As pointed by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246639/how-to-multiply-a-matrix-with-every-cell-of-cell-array-in-matlab/27246868#comment42974119_27246868) a more efficient way to `reshape` `B` would be

```
rB = reshape( cat( 5, B{:} ), numel(A), [] ).';
```

And a small benchmark can be found [here](https://ideone.com/SI59SI).

Comment: Should be pretty efficient.

Comment: @Divakar thanks. `reshaping` should be quite efficient, but I'm afraid `vertcat` might lead to large memory copy. It might be worth while considering reshaping and arranging so that the dot-product would be `rA*rB`...

Comment: I actually think you can avoid that `cellfun` which might be one of the slowest parts with this - `rB = reshape(cat(5,B{:}),numel(A),[]).';`. And you have to use one of the `cat`s somewhere anyway. After you have this `rB`, rest of your code should just take care of it.

Comment: @Divakar I was afraid of `cat`ing along 5th or 6th dimension and then transposing - it doesn't feel right, I fear it might entail a lot of memory copying.

Comment: That's the trade of course. But for me, I try to get off cell arrays as soon as possible if there are numeric computations involved. So I thought even the cat in the 5th dim could be worth the effort. This got me curious and here are some quick runtime results - https://ideone.com/SI59SI

Comment: @Divakar can you post it as a new answer - I'll upvote.

Comment: Oh no! When I saw the question, I started with `bsxfun(@times`, which would had been really inefficient and then I saw your answer and that led me to this cat in 5th dim idea, which I think is a minor adjustment to your solution. So it won't be fair :)